# error: invalid use of ‘class Animal::animalSound’

Tags: c++

could you please help me? I have a question about virtual functions.
I'm having a hard time getting this code to work. Could someone help me please? I can't get the attributes of the dog or cat to be printed at the end of the program.
This is the error code:
error: invalid use of ‘class Animal::soundDuringFeeding’
error: invalid use of ‘class Animal::animalSound’

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Animal
{
public:
    class soundDuringFeeding
    {
    public:
        virtual void eat() = 0;
    };

    class animalSound
    {
    public:
        virtual void meow() = 0;
        virtual void bark() = 0;
    };
};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:

    void bark()
    {
        cout<<"Au Au Au"<<endl;
    }
    void eat()
    {
        cout<<"Chomp chomp"<<endl;
    }
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
public:
    void meow()
    {
        cout<< "Miau"<<endl;
    }
    void eat()
    {
        cout<<"Slurp"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Animal *songs;

    int choose = 0;
    cout<<"Choose the animal: 1 - Dog | 2 - Cat"<<endl;
    cin>>choose;

    if(choose == 1)
    {
        songs = new Dog();
    }
    else if(choose == 2)
    {
        songs = new Cat();
    }
    songs->soundDuringFeeding;
    songs->animalSound;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question was not related to either C or Java. I've removed those tags and replaced with C++.

Comment: okay, thank you very much

Comment: You may have preconceptions about inner class definitions taken from other languages. In C++, an inner class definition (a class defined in another class) does not create any relationship between those classes except for how the inner class' identifier is qualified. The outer class does not implicitly posses an instance of the inner class and the inner class does not implicitly posses an instance of the outer class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your structure and understanding of inheritance is little off, eather way you have to use it like this to achive common behavior:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Animal
{
public:
    
    public:
        virtual void eat() = 0;
        // method has to have more general name but mainly the same name, the 
        // nested class action you were doing there was far from right, its as if
        // you just tried random staff 
        virtual void makeSound() = 0;

};

class Dog : public Animal
{
public:
    // renamed
    void makeSound()
    {
        cout<<"Au Au Au"<<endl;
    }
    void eat()
    {
        cout<<"Chomp chomp"<<endl;
    }
};

class Cat : public Animal
{
public:
    // renamed
    void makeSound()
    {
        cout<< "Miau"<<endl;
    }
    void eat()
    {
        cout<<"Slurp"<<endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Animal *a;

    int choose = 0;
    cout<<"Choose the animal: 1 - Dog | 2 - Cat"<<endl;
    cin>>choose;

    if(choose == 1)
    {
        a = new Dog();

    }
    else if(choose == 2)
    {
       a = new Cat();
    }

    // now you can call methods invoked with '()' syntax
    a->eat();
    a->makeSound();

    return 0;
}
```

i highli recomend entering `inheritance cpp` or `virtual cpp` to browser

Comment: How would this help the OP? There's no highlighted line in the answer, neither any explanation.

Comment: @RohanBari i kind of just shawed the answer there with no thinking, i added some comments but not sure if its enough

Comment: While answering, think like you're one of its visitors – so you realize when to comment and where.

Comment: Thank you very much . I'm starting c ++ programming and I really appreciate you helping me